# Spring p namespace for constructor args?

Tags: java, spring

Is there an equivalent of the [p namespace](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/11/25/xml-syntax-sugar-in-spring-20/) for constructor args in Spring? I would love to shorten that XML :)

Comment: The support has been added in 3.1, you will have to wait a while for it to be released.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent for constructor injection prior to 3.1, but you may consider [autowiring the constructor in your XML](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire) like this:

```
<bean id="beanId" class="..." autowire="constructor"/>
```

By autowiring, you do not have to specify the individual constructor args here as spring will work them out, just make sure you only have one bean of each type or spring will not be able to autowire them.

**EDIT:**

as @gkamal stated, from spring 3.1 onwards you can use the [c namespace for constructor injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-c-namespace).

Comment: Thanks. I usually don't do autowireing because the XML can serve as a good documentation for what's going on. But in this case I need to balance that with having to explicit documentation :)